# Basic IMDb scraper and movie generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I just built my first scraper and I'd like to get your thoughts on the structure and the way I went about it. The basic premise of the script:

1. Get a random movie from IMDb's Top 250
2. Ask the user whether they've seen it before. If yes, print another random movie. If no, tell them to enjoy the movie and the script ends.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

def moviePicker():
    hasSeen = False
    while hasSeen == False:
        import random
        page = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        random = random.randint(1, 250)

        title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(random) +']/td[2]/a/text()')
        yearReleased = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(random) + ']/td[2]/span/text()')

        # Parse the movie's url and pull the summary from the details page
        movieUrl = str(tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(random) + ']/td[2]/a/@href'))
        removeFront = movieUrl.replace("['", "")
        cleanUrl = 'http://www.imdb.com' + removeFront.replace("']", "")
        moviepage = requests.get(cleanUrl)
        details = html.fromstring(moviepage.content)
        movieSummary = details.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='summary_text']/text())")

        print(title)
        print(yearReleased)
        # print(cleanUrl)
        print(movieSummary)

        while True:
            answer = str.upper((input("Have you already watched this movie? Enter Y or N. : ")))
            if answer in ['Y', 'N']:
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter a Y or a N. ")
                continue
        if answer == 'Y':
            hasSeen = False
        elif answer == 'N':
            print("Enjoy the movie!")
            hasSeen = True

moviePicker()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that comes to attention is that you are repeating stuff unnecessarily.

Every loop, you try to `import random` and download the movie charts.

Importing `random` has only a small performance penalty, since Python will quickly notice that it is already imported, but there is some penalty nevertheless.

Downloading the charts again and again depends highly on the speed of your internet.

It is usually also good to separate your concerns into modular functions. This way you can easily swap out implementations or reuse them later.

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which programmers are encouraged to adhere to. It recommends using `lower_case_with_underscores` for variables and functions, instead of `camelCase`.

I would also use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to put the `n` into the path string and make the path strings themselves constants, which makes it easier to change them if IMDB ever changes their website.

Doing this, your code becomes:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import random

TITLE ='//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a/text()'
YEAR = '//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/span/text()'
URL = '//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a/@href'


def get_summary(url):
    moviepage = requests.get(url)
    details = html.fromstring(moviepage.content)
    return details.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='summary_text']/text())")


def get_movie(tree, n):
    title = tree.xpath(TITLE.format(n))
    year = tree.xpath(YEAR.format(n))
    url = str(tree.xpath(URL.format(n))).replace("['", "").replace("']", "")
    url = 'http://www.imdb.com' + url
    return title, year, url


def get_user_yn(message):
    while True:
        answer = input(message).upper()
        if answer in ('Y', 'N'):
            return answer == 'Y'
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a Y or a N. ")


def movie_picker():
    page = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)  
    while True:
        # Parse the movie's url and pull the summary from the details page 
        n = random.randint(1, 250)
        title, year, url = get_movie(tree, n)
        summary = get_summary(url)
        print(title)
        print(year)
        print(summary)
        if not get_user_yn("Have you already watched this movie? Enter Y or N. : "):
            print("Enjoy the movie!")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    movie_picker()
```

With this done, next I will focus on the actual implementation of these functions.

The parser you use is very manual. You have to pass the whole path to the element you are looking for. A more user-friendly parser is [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) from the module `bs4`. You can install it on Ubuntu/other Debian derivatives via `sudo apt install python-beautifulsoup`.

It has a method called `find` which returns the first tag matching some criteria. So to find the title, we can just do `soup.find("td", class_="titleColumn")`. Or use the `find_all` command to get a list of all matching tags. You will see that the parsing is a lot easier to follow with this, compared to `lxml`.

I would shuffle the movies list and then iterate over the shuffled list, guaranteeing that a movie will not be picked twice (during one run of the script).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random


def get_movies(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    movies = soup.find_all("td", class_="titleColumn")
    random.shuffle(movies)
    return movies


def get_summary(url):
    movie_page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(movie_page.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find("div", class_="summary_text").contents[0].strip()


def get_movie_info(movie):
    title = movie.a.contents[0]
    year = movie.span.contents[0]
    url = 'http://www.imdb.com' + movie.a['href']
    return title, year, url


def get_user_yn(message):
    while True:
        answer = input(message).upper()
        if answer in ('Y', 'N'):
            return answer == 'Y'
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a Y or a N. ")


def movie_picker():
    for movie in get_movies('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top'):
        # Parse the movie's url and pull the summary from the details page
        title, year, url = get_movie_info(movie)
        summary = get_summary(url)
        print(title, year)
        print(summary)
        if not get_user_yn("Have you already watched this movie? Enter Y or N. : "):
            print("Enjoy the movie!")
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    movie_picker()
```

Comment: the only thing I would change in your implementation is this part: `if answer in {'Y', 'N'}` . You would waste more time and memory to construct set rather than save it for `in lookup`. I would use tuple here. It's more common for such things.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, you are probably right. Fixed. Also added a Beautiful soup part :)

Comment: Would there be any benefit to using `'YN'` instead of `('Y', 'N')`?

Comment: @Ben Yes, there seems to be an advantage, probably because of the setup time of the tuple. `from timeit import Timer; Timer("'y' in 'NY'").timeit(); Timer("'y' in ('N', 'Y')").timeit()` gives about 0.4 vs 0.6 seconds.

Comment: @Ben But note that `YN` is now also a valid input, which returns `False`. So it is not exactly functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Graipher good points! You'd have to check the length of the response, which would negate any speed advantage I'm sure.

Comment: @Alex You are talking about the ms needed to *respond to console input* - there's no point speeding that up